# How to view a list from another class?

Tags: java, android, adapter

So, we've got a HomeFragment.java class with code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return rootView;
    }
```

And we created a another class ListGenerator.java with the following code:

```
public class ListGenerator extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        String[] lista_nazwisk = {"Krzysztof", "Bartek ", "Kamil "};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista_nazwisk);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

How can we display the items from the ListGenerator.java using the first class?

fragment_home.xml: http://pastebin.com/Lw7L2ikX

Comment: your HomeFragment.java is fragment and ListGenerator  is activity right ?

Comment: So you are looking for start a activity from fragment or show activity inside fragment ?

Comment: @Sree show activity inside fragment I think...

Comment: A Fragment can't host an activity. Instead of activity, you can use Nested Fragment

Comment: @Sree We want to show a list in one of fragments, but we can't do this in the fragment class because of "public class HomeFragment extends Fragment" and the adapter won't work.

Comment: So we decided to create another class which is ListGenerator.java for showing items from the list, and now we want to use it. 
Is it better to use this class in MainActivity or in fragment class (HomeFragment.java)?

Comment: First you need to study about android fragment and FragmentTransaction

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible but it would be easier to move the adapter initialization into the fragment that holds the listview that will show it.

HomeFragment.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
    String[] lista_nazwisk = {"Krzysztof", "Bartek ", "Kamil "};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista_nazwisk);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: So now I got http://pastebin.com/5nLMNY19 in HomeFragment.java
and get this error: http://pastebin.com/r2YbCndA

Comment: yeah, that was untested code. A `Fragment` is not a `Context`, which the `ArrayAdapter` needs in its constructor. In a fragment you can get the context by calling `getActivity()`. I've updated the code above, so try again with that.